# how to use shutl.disk_usage with a path

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, shutil

I am trying to use the disk_usage function from the shutil package.
Python version is 3.10.4

the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/shutil.html) state:

> **shutil.disk_usage(path)**
>
> Return disk usage statistics about the given path as a named tuple with the attributes total, used and free, which are the amount of
> total, used and free space, in bytes. path may be a file or a
> directory.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: On Windows, path can now be a file or directory.

These 3 code snipped should output the same but don't.
Using Jupyter Notebook inside Visual Studio Code on Windows11
How do I get the size of a directory with this function?

**Example1**

```
    from shutil import disk_usage
    import os
    print(disk_usage("C:/Users"))
    print(disk_usage("C:"))

>usage(total=999424712704, used=624119431168, free=375305281536)
>usage(total=999424712704, used=624119435264, free=375305277440)
```

**Example2**

```
    from shutil import disk_usage
    import os
    print(disk_usage("C:"))
    print(disk_usage(r"C:\Users"))

> usage(total=999424712704, used=624119824384, free=375304888320)
> usage(total=999424712704, used=624119824384, free=375304888320)
```

**Example3**
reversing the order makes a difference

```
from shutil import disk_usage
import os
print(disk_usage(r"C:\Users"))
print(disk_usage("C:"))

> usage(total=999424712704, used=624120086528, free=375304626176)
> usage(total=999424712704, used=624120090624, free=375304622080)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is that the jupyter notebook is written to the disk, changing the usage. Also probably some other processes are storing (temp files) on C between the executions.
Using a path to a flashdrive or secondary disc will probably be more stable.

disk_usage only gives stats on the disk, not folders.